# Minimal $T_0$-topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $\tau$ be a $T_0$-topology on $X$. Does $\tau$ contain a $T_0$-topology that is minimal with respect to $\subseteq$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Larson’s example in the paper cited by Tomek Kania and its verification are simple enough to be worth giving here (in very slightly modified form) for easy reference.

> Let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology on an uncountable set $X$, let $\tau_0\subseteq\tau$ be a $T_0$ topology on $X$, and let $\tau_0^*=\tau_0\setminus\{\varnothing\}$. For each $U\in\tau_0^*$ let $\tau_U=\{W\in\tau_0:U\subseteq W\text{ or }W\subseteq U\}$; clearly $\tau_U$ is a $T_0$ topology on $X$. If $\tau_0$ is minimal $T_0$, then $\tau_U=\tau_0$ for each $U\in\tau_0^*$, and $\langle\tau_0^*,\subseteq\rangle$ is a chain. But then $\langle\{X\setminus U:U\in\tau_0^*\},\subseteq\rangle$ is an uncountable chain of finite sets, which is absurd. Thus, $\tau$ contains no minimal $T_0$ topology.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. See

> K.-H. Pahk, Note on the characterizations of minimal $T_0$ and $T_D$ spaces, *Kyungpook Math. J.* **8** (1968), 5–10.

and

> R.E. Larson, [Minimal $T_0$-spaces and maximal $T_D$-spaces](http://msp.org/pjm/1969/31-2/pjm-v31-n2-p19-p.pdf), *Pacific J. Math.* **31** (1969), 451–458.