# is there coarsest $T_0$ topology on an arbitrary set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $τ$ be a $T_0$-topology on $X$ witch is NOT $T_1$. Does $τ$ contain a $T_0$-topology on $X$ that is minimal with respect to $⊆$ ?

[Minimal $T_0$-topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985631/minimal-t-0-topologies)

my question is similar to the link above but in my question $T_0$ spaces can't be  $T_1$ !

Comment: I realized that. That's why I got rid of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily; [Larson’s example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/986340/12042) at the linked question can be modified as follows.

Let $\langle Y,\tau_Y\rangle$ and $\langle Z,\tau_Z\rangle$ be disjoint uncountable spaces, each with the cofinite topology, let $X=Y\cup Z$, and let

$$\tau=\tau_Y\cup\{Y\cup U:U\in\tau_Z\}\;;$$

$\tau$ is a $T_0$ topology on $X$ that is not $T_1$.

Suppose that $\tau_0\subseteq\tau$ is a minimal $T_0$ topology. Let $\tau_0^*=\{U\in\tau_0:Y\subseteq U\}$, and for each $U\in\tau_0^*$ let

$$\tau_U=\{W\in\tau_0:W\subseteq U\text{ or }U\subseteq W\}\subseteq\tau_0\;.$$

It’s straightforward to check that $\tau_U$ is a $T_0$ topology on $X$, so $\tau_U=\tau_0$, and it follows that $\langle\tau_0^*,\subseteq\rangle$ is a chain. But then $\langle\{X\setminus U:U\in\tau_0^*\},\subseteq\rangle$ is an uncountable chain of finite subsets of $Z$, which is absurd.